# Permutate over output of CNN to return smallest loss and rearange output

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, keras, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

Lets say i am detecting dogs on images.

Output of my CNN is

```
Dense(24,activation="relu")
```

Which means i want to detect up to 6 dogs ( each dogs should be represented by xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = 4 values , 4 * 6 = 24 )

Now lets say i have two dogs on pictures and their positions are  ( bounding box )

```
dog1 = { xmin: 50, ymin:50, xmax:150,ymax:150}
dog2 = { xmin: 300,ymin:300,xmax:400,ymax:400}
```

Now tha label for this picture would look something like

```
( 50, 50, 150, 150, 300, 300, 400 ,400 , 0 ,0, 0 ... 16 zeros )
```

Now what if my CNN outputs something like

```
( 290, 285, 350 , 350, 60 , 40 , 120 ,110 ... 0 ... )
```

AS you can see the first bounding box that CNN outputs is closer to the bounding box of second dog and vice verse.

How should i deal with this?

I can create my own MSE function and output the smallest value e.g

```
def custom_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    tmp = 10000000000
    a = list(itertools.permutations(y_pred))
    for i in range(0, len(a)): 
     t = K.mean(K.square(a[i] - y_true), axis=-1)
     if t < tmp :
        tmp = t
     return tmp
```

But this would results only in "best" loss but the weights would get modified wrongly.

How can i modify output of CNN  ( permutate or rearrange elements ) so this would work?

I hope i explained it clearly.

Thanks for help.

Comment: My inclination is to use a different loss that takes the position of the predictions into consideration. Im not sure what `custom_mse` is doing but is it doing that? for instance here is a loss function I just found:   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319243/object-detection-loss-function-yolo

Comment: isnt it just mean squared error function? I dont see anything there that helps with position

Comment: @putonspectacles also my loss function permutates the output vector and return the smallest loss

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in on what object you calculate the loss.
Tensorflow/Keras/Almost any other library, uses its own objects in order to find derivatives and define the calculation graph.
Therefore, if you need to do anything with the graph, you must do it using a defined op *or* **define your own op using the given methods and objects**. Tensorflow also allows to wrap regular python functions and make it as ops on tensors.

As for your problem, create a `2d` output array of dims `[4,num_of_objects]` and use tensorflow operations to reorder the second dimension before calculating loss. See full lists [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/array_ops). Split it according to second dimension, iterate combinations, use `tf.min` to find the minimum loss, and optimize only the minimum loss. **Experimented with that approach, it works, also with bounding boxes.**

**EDIT**: Noted that you perform your experiments and calculation with *Keras*, use *Tensorflow* backend and work only on tensors, do NOT retreive data from graph to numpy/list objects. Use only tensors.

Good luck!